# Rails: How do I show all the users post? undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was testing out a blog. If a user posts in the blog, when they go to the index, it shows all the users name. But if the user logs out and go to the index page, they get an error.

```
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

It seems to not show the other users post unless he or she is logged in or this error comes. Why is that happening? Any help would be appreciated.

index.html

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 

      <%= image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
      <%= link_to post.user.name, @post.user %> 
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Which index page? users or posts? Which line of code throws the error?

Comment: Mainly this code causes the issue in posts `<%= image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>`

Comment: `if  @user = current_user` shouldn't this be `==` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 
  <% unless post.user.blank? %>
    <%= image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
    <%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It still give me the error `undefined method user for nil:NilClass`, it only happens if the user is not signed in. :(

Comment: instead of `@post` it should be `post`

Comment: The error said `undefined method user for nil:NilClass` not `undefined method avatar for nil:NilClass` So, how would the check `unless post.user.blank?` be the fix for this problem. I guess the actual fix would have been `<%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %>` instead of `<%= link_to post.user.name, @post.user %>`

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
<%= link_to post.user.name, @post.user %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to post.user.name, post.user %>
```

Comment: This is the code that causes the issues,  `<%= image_tag(post.user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>`

Comment: This is correcting a bug though, unless you really want to link to one specific post throughout the loop, if `@post` is defined, or nowhere if not.